# Monster hunter: influence of armor size

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In the Monster hunter franchise (I am interested above all to MH Generations or MH X) the player can craft and wear several different armors.

Some of them are quite tight to the body, some instead have horns, mantles and overall a bigger "encumbrance".

I wonder if having a bulkier armor provides a bigger hitbox for the monsters. Of course different armors have different defensive features, but I do not know if for the monster is easier to hit a bulkier player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hitbox of the player is always the same. It's not changed by gender or worn armor.